# Images are not getting uploaded from Android to Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload image to Firebase via Android app . 
On pressing Upload button and after setting the image from storage, it just remains uploading all the time. In brief,uploading task is never getting successfull.

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.test3;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.Storage;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btn_upload,btn_choose;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Uri filePath;
    private FirebaseStorage storage;
    private StorageReference storageReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_choose =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_choose);
        btn_upload =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_upload);
        imageView =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference = storage.getReference();

        btn_upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                uploadImage();
            }

        });
        btn_choose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chooseImage();
            }
        });
    }

    private void chooseImage() {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Image"),1);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null && data.getData()!=null){
            filePath = data.getData();

            try {
               Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),filePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    private void uploadImage() {
        if (filePath != null) {
            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
            progressDialog.show();

            StorageReference reference = storageReference.child("images/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            reference.putFile(filePath)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                         double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                           progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+(int)progress+"%");
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

I have only one activity.
This is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:id="@+id/myImage"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_choose"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_rounded"
        android:text="Choose"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn_upload"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_rounded"
            android:text="Upload"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I just for similar problems on goolge but none of them solves my issue.'
My code works fine on Android Studio. 
My Firebase is connected to my app.

Comment: Add an addOnFailureListener. And see where the problem is!

Comment: Now, I got it since Firebase new version has bit awkward rules so I just modified it take any object.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a notorious inefficient interactive debugger, so you'll have to tell us waht happens when you run this code in the debugger and place breakpoints. Does your `onProgress` ever get triggered? How about `onSuccess`?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen, as I have mentioned in new version of Firebase,  modification of my rules in storage did my work.